# How to sort a SQL table using C# code ASP.net-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with tickets system, and whenever I remove a ticket and add a new one, the new ticket comes in the place of the old one with a different ID.

For example if I remove the ticket with id = 4 and add another ticket, my table would be like:

```
ID : 1      TicketInfo..
ID : 2      TicketInfo..
ID : 3      TicketInfo..
ID : 56     TicketInfo..
ID : 5      TicketInfo..
```

I'm trying to place a **sort** statement (if possible) so its executed every time I add a ticket.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you show a little more code?

Comment: what codes, i just want a way to sort a SQL table depending on id, in c# not SQL.

Comment: When you remove a ticket and add another you have two operations happening. It would be helpful to see how you are handling the insert operation. Also- Are you using ID as a primary key in your table?

Comment: @user2962142 "What codes" = how are you retrieving your data?  EF?  Linq?  Raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you would do the sort at the SQL End, not the C# end. otherwise if you wanted to, then you need to implement an IComparer

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing SQL just add an ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Tickets
ORDER BY ID
```

If you are using Linq just add an `OrderBy` call:

```
var tix = db.Tickets
            .OrderBy(t => t.ID)
            .ToList()
```